# Infinite Loop sending email from excel 2007

Tags: excel

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Sub SendEMail()
    Dim Email As String, Subj As String
    Dim Msg As String, URL As String
    Dim r As Integer, x As Double
    For r = 2 To 2000 'data in rows 2-4
'       Get the email address
        Email = Cells(r, 6)

'       Message subject
        Subj = "bug"

'       Compose the message
        Msg = ""
        Msg = Msg & "Dear " & Cells(r, 6) & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "Please Validate thebug Waiting on You "

        Msg = Msg & Cells(r, 1).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "S" & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "RTS"

'       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
        Subj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Subj, " ", "%20")
        Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, " ", "%20")

'       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
        Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
'       Create the URL
        URL = "mailto:" & Email & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg

'       Execute the URL (start the email client)
        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, URL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

'       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
    Next r
End Sub
```

help me debug this, its going to infinity loop

Comment: Can you describe what's happening?  Is it sending the same email over and over?  What happens when you run it in debug mode?  Are there really 2000 emails that go out?

Comment: I'd start by defining `r as Long`.

Comment: @Hambone:yes  it is sending email over and over. more than 100 email came then i have to go back and stop the task manager

Comment: I must admit -- nothing jumps out at me, which gives me two thoughts.  1. What does your spreadsheet data look like?  Can you post a screen shot or an extract?  2. What about the code that calls `SendEMail`?  Can you add the code block where it's called so I can see under what conditions it's used?